# how can i take value grants from method grant_calculation and put it to my class object student1

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, object

How can i get value grants to my object student1. Sorry Im new in python and dont know how those things are working. I dont understand why grants value which must be not 70.0 when average_mark is more than 9 still 70.0.

```
    class Students:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, course_number, average_mark, standart_grants, grants):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.course_number = course_number
        self.average_mark = average_mark
        self.standart_grants = standart_grants
        self.grants = grants

    def grant_calculation(self):
        if self.average_mark >= 9:
            grants = self.standart_grants * 0.75
        elif 6 >= self.average_mark <= 8:
            grants = self.standart_grants * 0.5
        else:
            grants = self.standart_grants
        return grants

    def show(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.surname)
        print(self.age)
        print(self.course_number)
        print(self.average_mark)
        print(self.standart_grants)
        print(self.grants)
student1 = Students("Arni", "Gandalf", 19, 3, 9, 70.0, 70.0)
student1.grant_calculation()
Students.show(student1)
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!
this looks like a homework question! have a good read on [asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6619250) and come back and [edit] your post if u want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grants` is a local variable with no meaning outside the `Students.grant_calculation(self)` method, unless stored somewhere. The variable you're looking for is `self.grants`, i.e.:

```py
    def grant_calculation(self):
        if self.average_mark >= 9:
            self.grants = self.standart_grants * 0.75
        elif 6 >= self.average_mark <= 8:
            self.grants = self.standart_grants * 0.5
        else:
            self.grants = self.standart_grants
```

Also, there is no need to return the value if you're not using it outside of the method.

Alternatively, you can keep that function as is and update it outside, by assigning its result to `student1.grants`:

```py
student1.grants = student1.grant_calculation()
```